# pseudorandom pattern generator, output is not changing

Tags: vhdl

I am using modelsim for simulating a pseudo-random pattern generator using the below code. The problem is when i force the data_reg signal to a seed value (ex: 0001010101101111) the data_out shows the same value instead of a random value. i will really appreciate any help i cud get on this one.

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

 entity dff is
 Port ( CLK : in std_logic;
       RSTn : in std_logic;
       D : in std_logic;
       Q : out std_logic);
   end dff;

   architecture Behavioral of dff is
      begin
       process(CLK)
       begin
    if CLK'event and CLK='1' then
    if RSTn='1' then
    Q <= '1';

 else
    Q <= D;
    end if;
    end if;
    end process;
    end Behavioral;
```

VHDL CODE FOR PRBS Generator using LFSR:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity lfsr is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RSTn : in  STD_LOGIC;
           data_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end lfsr;

architecture Behavioral of lfsr is

component dff
Port ( CLK : in std_logic;
           RSTn : in std_logic;
           D : in std_logic;
           Q : out std_logic);
end component;

signal data_reg : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal tap_data : std_logic;

begin
  process(CLK)
  begin
  tap_data <= (data_reg(1) xor data_reg(2)) xor (data_reg(4) xor
  data_reg(15));
  end process;

  stage0: dff
    port map(CLK, RSTn, tap_data, data_reg(0));

g0:for i in 0 to 14 generate
    stageN: dff
      port map(CLK, RSTn, data_reg(i), data_reg(i+1));
  end generate;
  data_out <= data_reg after 3 ns;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

First off. In your LFSR you have a process sensitive to CLK which should only be combinational:

```vhdl
process(CLK) -- Not correct

-- Change to the following (or "all" in VHDL-2008)
process(data_reg)
```

You could also just implement it as a continuous assignment outside of a formal process which is functionally the same in this case.

When you force `data_reg` to a value you are overriding the normal signal drivers instantiated in the design. In the GUI the force command defaults to "Freeze". Once that is in place, the drivers can't update `data_reg` because the freeze force is dominant until you cancel it. In the force dialog select the "Deposit" kind to change the state without overriding the drivers on subsequent clocks.

The Modelsim documentation has this to say about the different force kinds:

- freeze -- Freezes the item at the specified value until it is forced again or until it is unforced with a noforce command.
- drive -- Attaches a driver to the item and drives the specified value until the item is forced again or until it is unforced with a noforce command. This option is illegal for unresolved signals.
- deposit -- Sets the item to the specified value. The value remains until there is a subsequent driver transaction, or until the item is forced again, or until it is unforced with a noforce command

Note: While a lot of instructional materials (unfortunately) demonstrate the use of the `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_unsigned` libraries, these are not actual IEEE standards and shouldn't be used in standard conformant VHDL. Use `numeric_std` instead or, in your case, just eliminate them since you aren't using any arithmetic from those libraries.

Comment: god bless u with his choicest blessings kevin:) u r a hero ;) i have no words to thank you ...it worked just perfectly :) god bless u :) i hv to submit it in an hour ...u came to my rescue :)

Comment: i forgot to tag u...i am new here :p thankyou once again..and if you can help me out in another query here is the link to that page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581166/low-power-test-pattern-generator